# Sorting array with the search text

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array:

```
$strings = [
    '1'=>'Hie bye why',
    '2'=>'abc xyz pqr',
    '3'=>'abc xyz lmn'
];
```

I have a search string, `abc xyz pqr`. I want to sort the array so that the string matching the search string should be at the first position in the array and so on

ie. `abc xyz pqr` should be at first not `abc xyz lmn`.

How can I do this?

Comment: play with usort strcmp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

```php
<?php

$strings = [
    '1'=>'Hie bye why',
    '2'=>'abc xyz pqr',
    '3'=>'abc xyz lmn'
];

$search = 'abc xyz pqr';


// Debugging
echo 'Before sort:';
echo '<pre>'.print_r($strings,true).'</pre>';

// Sort the array
usort($strings, function($a, $b) use ($search) {
    return ($search == $a) ? -1 : 1;
});

// Debugging
echo 'After sort:';
echo '<pre>'.print_r($strings,true).'</pre>';
```